# Node and route management

Tags: node.js

I have written following code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var fileName = 'site/index.html';
var encoding = 'utf-8';
var dataContent = "";

fs.readFile(fileName, encoding, function(error, data) {
    if(error) throw error;
    dataContent = data;
});

var requestListener = function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Length': dataContent.length,
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        'connection': 'keep-alive',
        'accept': '*/*'
    });

    response.end(dataContent);
}

var server = http.createServer(requestListener, function(connect) {
    connect.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Server disconnected...');
    });
});

server.listen(8000, function() {
    console.log("Server is listening...");
});
```

I have 2 files in site directory:

```
 1. index.html
 2. aboutus.html
```

Step 1: I run the above code using node command as node runServer.js

Step 2: Now i have opened the browser and typed the following url

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

The browser is showing me the content of index.html correctly.
And the index.html file contents some raw text and link to another file i.e. aboutus.html

Step3: When i click the click the link for aboutus.html the browser change the url into following

```
http://localhost:8000/aboutus.html
```

but the content of aboutus.html is not display, instead it shows me the content of index.html

I know that this is happening because the fileName variable content 'site/index.html'. So the browser is rendering the index.html content

How can i change this behavior? If i am not using express.js

---

Now, i made few changes in the following code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var fileName = "site/index.html";
var encoding = 'utf-8';
var dataContent = "";

function readContentFile(fileName) {
    console.log(fileName);
    fs.readFile(fileName, encoding, function(error, data) {
        if(error) throw error;
        dataContent = data;
    });
}

readContentFile(fileName);

var requestListener = function(request, response) {

    filePath = request.url;    
    if(filePath!='/') {
        fileName = 'site' + filePath;
        readContentFile(fileName);
    }

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Length': dataContent.length,
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        'connection': 'keep-alive',
        'accept': '*/*'
    });

    response.end(dataContent);
}

var server = http.createServer(requestListener, function(connect) {



    connect.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Server disconnected...');
    });
});

server.listen(8000, function() {
    console.log("Server is listening...");
});
```

Still its not working, Is any thing wrong in my code.
or i should go for express.js

Comment: Any particular reason not to use Express?

Comment: i am new in node.js
so, i was thinking not to use express.js

Comment: One of the first frameworks I started using when I was new to Node was Express :)

Comment: I think especially for new Node.js developer it makes sense not to use express to learn first how Node.js basicly works. If have gathered some experience with the Node.js basics, you can use Express or another framework to save time in development.

Comment: @Cromax I *kinda* agree, but on the other hand, using modules made by other smart people is part of the Node ecosystem as well :)

Comment: @robertklep: That'S right. I am using flatiron for example. But my first projects were without those frameworks, because i wanted to understand how it works. Till now there are some errors which i would don't understand if i wouldn't know how Node.js is working without those frameworks. Especially Express is doing very much for you and on the other hand it is hiding very much functionality for you. That's good for faster development but not good for learning and understanding Node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example of a static server

take a look @ http://runnable.com/UUgnuT2wDj1UAGSe

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/') {
    req.url = '/index.html';
  }
  var file = path.join(__dirname,req.url);
  path.exists(file, function (exists) {
    if (exists) {
      fs.stat(file, function (err, stats) {
        if(err) {
          throw err;
        }
        if (stats.isFile()) {
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
          fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(res);
        } else {
          res.writeHead(404);
          res.end('not found');
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end('not found');
    }
  });
}).listen( 8000 );

console.log('Server running on port ' + 8000);
```

note: this is using node 0.6.x the apis have changed a bit since then, fs.exists, instead of path.exists.

Comment: True, it's an example of using the path and fs api, with callbacks and pipes.  But it's far from production code, just a POC.

Comment: D:\NodeJS>node RunServer.js
Server running on port undefined
^C
D:\NodeJS>

Comment: just change out `.listen( process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT, process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP );` to your choice of port

Comment: @generalhenry that's the issue with implementing this yourself, though, you need to be aware (as you are) there's a security risk involved. I've seen it happen too often that people upgrade POC to production 'because it works'.

Comment: Feel free to post a secure version, it would be too big to really serve as a good tinkering example.  Though on that note it is useful to read through a proper implementation such as https://github.com/visionmedia/send/blob/master/lib/send.js

Comment: @generalhenry I'd just use `app.use(express.static(...))`

Comment: As a note send.js is the same thing as express.static, just pulled into it's own module. And yes, I always just use express.static, even though the best answer is to use nginx, node.js isn't that good of a static file server.